# BufferGeometry transparency

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

In BufferGeometry, we can use material setting `{vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors}` to set different colors for faces. But there is no way to set transparency.

How do you set transparency for different faces in BufferGeometry?

Comment: Let me know what kind of material you are using... Try to apply "opacity" to your material

Comment: Thanks. But I want to set opacity only on some faces of the BufferGeometry.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that has been solved in the `dev` branch.

Take a look at this example:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_rawshader.html

Comment: Would THREE.Color be extended with the alpha component? Or must we use the new RawShaderMaterial?

Comment: By now you mush use the new `RawShaderMaterial` and build your own attributes.

Comment: I increased the number of triangles to 100k and the frame rate drops to 10 fps. Strange because there are only a few draw calls and the shader is simple. Any reason why?